# Study design involving 4 variables measured every month for 5 years

Tags: time-series, mean

I want to design a study on hemodialysis patients. I know from basic science knowledge that there are four variables (suppose  a, b, c, d) which effect the rates of heart attacks/ strokes and amputation in hemodialysis patients. My objective is to prove that all these have a correlation with heart attacks/ strokes and amputation in dialysis patients. After proving I want to find out which variable has the strongest link with ANY of these events. 
Now I have 88 dialysis patient in my hospital and have the variable data for a, b, c, d in excel form monthly for 5yrs. How can I use these variables a, b, c, d which will be 12 times in the year and 60 in 5yrs. How is time averaging done?

Let me explain more. I will only take one adverse event heart attack for now. Increase in variable A and B increases risk of heart attack and increase in variable C and D decrease risk of heart attack. How should I design a restrospective study over 5yrs to maximize the chance of finding a significance between the above mentioned hypothesis?

Variables a to d are not binary but rather continuous with limits ofcourse. Example variable C ranges from 1 to 4mg/dl in the blood. The optimum level is 4mg/dl, the lower the level the higher risk of heart attack. Now how should I analyse my data to maximize the chance of finding an association between heart attacks and low level of variable C. I will use the similar strategy for all variables. What test will I use and where can I get the software to do those tests?

I am sorry I dont know the meaning of time average. There is a study that I heard about with a similar idea. They used a variable measured every month for a few years. I am not sure how they time averaged? Perhaps it is the arithmetic mean? This is the study that uses time averaging- Dialysis Modality and Correction of Uremic Metabolic Acidosis: Relationship with All-Cause and Cause-Specific Mortality Tania Vashistha, Kamyar Kalantar-Zadeh. It appeared in the journel CJASN. The link is here- http://cjasn.asnjournals.org/content/early/2012/11/21/CJN.05780612.abstract

Is there a way to attach pdf then I can with this question. Thanks to all in advance

Comment: Normally one "designs" a study *before* collecting the data: it sounds like you want to *analyze* study data. What information do you have about the heart attacks and strokes? What exploratory analysis of the data have you considered? What do you mean by "time averaging"?

Comment: I interpret this to mean that a, b, c and d change over time - they ar enot intrinsic things for the patient (eg they are not like height, or ethnicity).  One of your questions to address is whether it is a change in these variables that is linked to heart attacks etc, or the base level.

Answer (score -3):

The values for four variables a,b,c,d (which effect the rates of heart attacks/ strokes and amputation in hemodialysis patients ) is measured per month. So, I think that the time factor should be averaged to make the value observed in per month. For example , feature a for patient A will have 12 values for one year and 60 for 5 yrs, so, all the 60 values should be summed and divided by 60 which will give a resultant value x/month. The same procedure should be followed for other features as well. At last we will have 88 rows (patients) and 4 columns (features).

Comment: Because this proposal collapses each time series of 60 values into one mean, it seems likely it will lose a tremendous amount of potentially useful information. For instance, one would guess that *changes* or *trends* in the explanatory variables $a,b,c,$ and $d$ might be related to the endpoints, but taking the means loses all such information.

Comment: Hello, thanks everyone. Let me explain. I will only take one adverse event heart attack for now. Increase in variable A and B increases risk of heart attack and increase in variable C and D decrease risk of heart attack. How should I design a restrospective study over 5yrs to maximize the chance of finding a significance? I was thinking for that I will also need to find the general event rate of heart attack in dialysis patients. How else can I calculate the power of the study or the number needed to prove an association. I only have 88 patients

Comment: Variables a to d are not binary but rather continuous with limits ofcourse. Example variable C ranges from 1 to 4mg/dl in the blood. The optimum level is 4mg/dl, the lower the level the higher risk of heart attack. Now how should I analyse my data to maximize the chance of finding an association between heart attacks and low level of variable C. I will use the similar strategy for all variables. What test will I use and where can I get the software to do those tests?

Comment: I am sorry I dont know the meaning of time average. There is a study that I heard about with a similar idea. They used a variable measured every month for a few years. I am not sure how they time averaged? Perhaps it is the arithmetic mean? I am thinking I have 12 values/yr and 60 in 5yrs, what is the best representative value? Or should I use all these values for correlating with a heart attack. How can I use all these values? What formula/ test to use?

Comment: Sairah, most people will not see your last three comments. Please incorporate them within your question.  As far as "time averaging" goes, please provide a citatation (and preferably a link) to the study you refer to, so that we may investigate what was intended.

Comment: Hi whuber, I provided more information. Please comment, thanks